# Vue - array to columns with modulo (%)

Tags: vue.js

Is there a way to create such table with modulo on Vue? I was stuck with how it would loop.

| data | data | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foo | bar | baz |
| foobar | foobaz | bazbar |

**sample data**

```
array: ['foo','bar','baz','foobar','foobaz','bazbar']
```

**template**

```
<tbody v-for="(data,index) in array" :key="index">
  <tr v-if="index%3===0">
    <td v-for="i in 3" :key="i">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" :value="data"
        <label class="form-check-label">
          {{ data }}
        </label>
       </div>
     </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure this is not ideal (I never used vue before).
I just split the iteration into 2 loops, and calculate the actual index into the data-array on the fly.

```
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(_x, n) in Math.ceil(array.length / 3)" :key="n">
      <td v-for="(_y, m) in 3" :key="m" :set="item = array[n * 3 + m]">
        <div v-if="item" class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" :value="item"/>
          <label class="form-check-label">
            {{ item }}
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Here runnable version: note the warning at the console so I guess vue is complaining about something I am not aware of.

https://jsfiddle.net/79ngb523/